# connect to android via adb wifi without knowing device ip address

Tags: android, adb

i know that we can connect device over WiFi. i need a batch script for windows to do it automatically. these three steps needed:
1. start the adb daemon listening on TCP on the specified port

```
adb tcpip <port>
```

2. get ip address of android device. i know that with `adb shell ifconfig wlan0` i can get information about wlan0 interface, some info like:

```
wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dee8:38ff:fe08:7322/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:597 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:187557 TX bytes:106180
```

but i need just ip address of wlan0.
3. if i know device_ip then i can do  `adb connect device_ip`

How to do this process automatically in just one batch script in windows?
Hoe to do it in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. just two commands:
In Windows:

```
adb tcpip 5555
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:, " %i  in ('adb shell ifconfig wlan0 ^| findstr /c:"inet addr"') do adb connect %i
```

Comment: In `.bat`: use `%%i` instead. In PowerShell: `.\adb.exe shell ifconfig wlan0 | Select-String "inet addr" | ForEach-Object { .\adb.exe connect $_.ToString().Split(":")[1].Split(" ")[0] }`. Common: `ap0` hotspot, `inet addr:192.168`.